# monit can not resolve hostname: getaddrinfo does not find host

Tags: debian, monit

I use monit v5.16 running on Debian Wheezy to check if a server is up or down using the ping instruction.

Here is my configuration:

```
check host my.server.domain with address my.server.domain
       mode passive
       every 5 cycles
       if failed ping4 count 5 then alert  # IPv4 only
       if failed ping6 count 5 then alert  # IPv6 only
```

I always get the following error:

```
[CET Mar  1 23:28:32] error    : Ping for my.server.domain -- getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
[CET Mar  1 23:28:32] error    : 'my.server.domain' ping test failed
```

If I ping from the command line, everything works fine:

```
PING my.server.domain (yy.yyy.yyy.yyy) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from myoffice.com (xx.xxx.xx.xxx): icmp_req=1 ttl=54 time=1147 ms
```

I do not want to put anything into my /etc/hosts or anything hardcoded on the server where monit is running.

What could I do to solve this ? Is it a bug ?

Should I use another version of monit ? Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here came from the fact that I added a `ping6` instruction.

`ping4` (or `ping`) alone will work. Adding `ping6` makes this check fail (and leads to the `getaddrinfo failed` error).

Comment: You fix that by putting in your AAAA record into your DNS

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tested and actually the error has changed (Network is unreachable). So I guess it works better but I lack some IPv6 support on my local network or something like that.